# is it possible to use linq with NHibernate just like with linq2sql or entity framework?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate and would like to use linq to query my database is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [NHibernate Linq](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx)

Here are some examples:

[Fluent NHibernate and Linq to NHibernate Demo Project](http://emiajnet.blogspot.com/2009/04/fluent-nhibernate-and-linq2nhibernate.html)

[RhinoCommons, NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC Part 5 - LINQ to NHibernate](http://frickinsweet.com/ryanlanciaux.com/post/RhinoCommons2c-NHibernate-and-ASPNET-MVC-Part-5---LINQ-to-NHibernate.aspx)
[LINQ for NHibernate Examples](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/8/17/linq-for-nhibernate-examples/)

Comment: could you give me some link on how to use it ?